# Resample with DateOffset can give NotImplementedError

Tags: pandas

Docs for [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) say it can take a [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) as the **rule**.
But trying this out sometimes results in a `NotImplementedError`.

- Passing a string e.g. `resample('2M')` works.
- The equivalent `resample(pd.offsets.MonthEnd(2))` also works.
- But the similar (though different) `resample(pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=2))` fails.

Here's code to reproduce:

```py
idx = pd.date_range('20190101', periods=14, freq='3W')
s   = pd.Series(range(len(idx)), index=idx)
s.resample(pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=2)).mean()
```

Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ....
  File "....core\generic.py", line 8449, in resample
    level=level,
  File "....core\resample.py", line 1305, in resample
    tg = TimeGrouper(**kwds)
  File "....core\resample.py", line 1378, in __init__
    rule = freq.rule_code
  File "....tseries\offsets.py", line 442, in rule_code
    return self._prefix
  File "....tseries\offsets.py", line 438, in _prefix
    raise NotImplementedError("Prefix not defined")
NotImplementedError: Prefix not defined
```

Am I right that [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) supports only certain [`DateOffsets`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html)?

What kinds doesn't/does it support?

Comment: The equivalent to '2M' would be `s.resample(pd.offsets.MonthEnd(2)).mean()`

Comment: @ChristophBühler There is a bug report on this issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31697

Comment: The bug seem not to be treated yet. Does anybody discovered another way of doing it? Maybe converting DateOffset to string somehow...

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have stated it is a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31697) but you can work around it:

> According to the documentation, the rule= parameter of
> DataFrame.resample() can be of type DateOffset, Timedelta or str.
> Apparently, it actually expects some of the DateOffset subclasses
> (like MonthEnd, BusinessDay, etc.), because rule_code attribute is not
> defined in the parent class.

You can either use an equivalent `TimeDelta` or one of the subclasses of `DateOffset`